# How to spoof IP to show I'm in the US?

Tags: ip, router, internet, spoofing

I'm interested in purchasing a router so that I can (not sure what the term is called) "spoof?" my IP to show that I'm in the US. I moved to Mexico and and I brought my computer from the US. I'm trying to get my IP to say that I'm in the US. How do I go about doing that? What requirements does the router need in order for this to work? And can I do it so it shows that I'm in a specific part of the US? Do I need some type of VPN that I need to pay monthly? What do I need to get this done?

Comment: you cannot spoof your IP and still be able to connect to anything - you are looking for a VPN service in the US, not a router - note that many VPN IPs are known and whoever you are trying to deceive might know you are using a VPN

Comment: So it won't be possible is what you are saying?

Comment: So I can't spoof my IP using a router?

Comment: @AlexJimenez: no, you can't just by using the router. You need a VPN with an endpoint in the US.

Comment: If you want your IP to appear to come from the US, you need a VPN

Comment: but as schroeder said, they other side might know I am using a VPN

Comment: Also... if I use a VPN.... can I connect to another VPN while on the VPN?

Comment: Your question appears to be about network infrastructure and OSI layers architecture.  Not really about information security.

Comment: CAn you guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to spoof your IP in a way that makes it possible to surf the web. If you send IP packets with a spoofed IP, the responses will go to that IP and not yours. That means you will not be able to start a TCP connection, which means you will not be able to connect to a webpage with HTTP, which mean you can not surf the web.

No fancy functionality in a router will change that.

What you need instead is a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) with an endpoint in the US. The IP of many VPN:s are on lists, though, so even with a VPN there is a risk that whoever you are trying to fool will catch you.